# What could be causing UDP Packet timings to be inconsistent?

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, networking, udp

I have been working on a project which reads mouse input, and then sends it via UDP to another computer where the mouse input is then recreated. I am having strange issues with UDP packet timings, only on one of my computers, where it seems as though the UDP packets may be being grouped together? I have set up some simple code which sends a udp packet of about 12 bytes every 10ms

```
while(true)
{
    Packet p = new Packet(Packet.Type.MOUSE_MOVE, id++, (float)50, (float)50);
    Send(p);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

however, my server which receives these packets does not receive one packet every 10ms as i would expect.

instead, measuring the 'time since last packet' shows these timings:

```
[1440] [6.0834ms]   MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1441] [8.4989ms]   MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1442] [9.7771ms]   MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1443] [59.8888ms]  MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1444] [0ms]        MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1445] [0.4995ms]   MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1446] [0.4985ms]   MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1447] [0ms]        MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1448] [0ms]        MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1449] [6.0016ms]   MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1450] [6.001ms]    MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1451] [10.0007ms]  MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1452] [64.4198ms]  MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1453] [0ms]        MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1454] [0.5021ms]   MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1455] [0ms]        MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1456] [0.5017ms]   MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1457] [0ms]        MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1458] [5.4997ms]   MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1459] [7.4957ms]   MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1460] [10.5004ms]  MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1461] [66.7724ms]  MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1462] [0ms]        MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1463] [1.5007ms]   MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1464] [0ms]        MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
[1465] [0ms]        MOUSE_MOVE: 50, 50
```

Clearly, there must be something outside of my code, or some setting in the UdpClient that is changing the timings behind the scenes, otherwise I dont see how it could be possible that my server is receiving packets with <1ms delay between packets, when the client is only sending a packet every 10ms.

Another noteworthy thing, is that sometimes the 'time between packets' measurement spikes up to around 60ms. I measured how often this happens, and it appears to spike every 100ms (give or take 1 or 2 milliseconds)

Based on this, I believe something must be buffering or grouping packets together before sending them, probably gathering all packets for 100ms and then sending them all at once.

One more thing, I've only experienced this type of grouping on one test computer, which makes me believe maybe its an OS or Driver issue. The issue is only happening on a Microsoft Surface Go, so it could possibly be related to it being a somewhat under powered device. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

the client is created like so:

```
var ip = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 178, 63 });
endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, Common.Constants.SERVER_PORT);
client = new UdpClient();
client.Connect(endPoint);
```

and the Send function:

```
private void Send(Packet p)
{
    var data = p.ToByteArray();
    client.Send(data, data.Length);
}
```

the receiving thread:

```
    private static void ServerThread()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            var clientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            var clientData = server.Receive(ref clientEndPoint);

            if (clientData.Length > 0)
            {

                Packet p = new Packet(clientData);

                var time = DateTime.Now - last;

                Console.WriteLine($"[{p.id}] [{time.TotalMilliseconds}ms] {p.type}: {p.x}, {p.y}");

                last = DateTime.Now;

                if (p.type == Packet.Type.MOUSE_MOVE)
                {
                    SetCursorPos((int)p.x, (int)p.y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's all kinds of reasons this can happen.  UDP packets can and will get batched together no matter what you do.  But there are socket options that will relieve some of the irregularities and dispatch faster.  But you need to show the code that shows how the socket was created. Preferably show the code for `Send` as well. And your `recv` code as well.

Comment: Also, just because you invoke `Sleep(10)` doesn't mean you are going to wake up exactly 10ms either.  No matter what, you have to be prepared to handle jitter in your code on the send side and the receive - especially if you are sending 100 packets per second.  Another question: Why do you care about the mouse movement for anything but the last packet anyway?

Comment: @selbie I added that extra info you asked for, I would assume that calling `Sleep(10)` would atleast sleep for more than 1ms though. As for why I need consistent mouse movement for every packet, is that the project is for remote work specifically on digital drawing / sculpting, so the shape of the strokes is vital. Do you have any examples of the socket options you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have found a solution, by disabling 'Microsoft Virtual WiFi Adapter', the packet timing seems to have become more consistent.

in elevated command prompt:

`netsh wlan stop hostednetwork`

`netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line :

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
```

The system's timer is not very accurate.
You can find more accurate timers to do this.